# Delete - Trigger

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008

I wrote this trigger below. it is generating Error at:

`Where UAssignment_Rights.user_id =i.user_id`

`from Inserted i`

I want that when any row Deletes from Users table. *It should also delete `Deleted User` Details from `UAssignment_Rights Table`.*
[image]

Here in Image above `Normalized Table is named as UAssignment_Rights`

```
CREATE TRIGGER Trigger_Update ON Users
FOR DELETE
AS
    set nocount on
DELETE 
FROM   UAssignment_Rights

        Where UAssignment_Rights.user_id =i.user_id
        from Inserted i

       PRINT 'AFTER INSERT trigger fired.'
```

Can anyone answer my this question! Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your syntax is wrong for deleting with a `JOIN`. Try this instead:

```
CREATE TRIGGER Trigger_Update ON Users
FOR DELETE
AS
SET NOCOUNT ON;

DELETE UR
FROM   UAssignment_Rights UR
INNER JOIN Deleted D
ON UR.[user_id] = D.[user_id]

PRINT 'AFTER INSERT trigger fired.'
```

Also, this is for SQL Server (which seems to be the actual RDBMS that you are using, I don't know why you tagged this question with MySQL too)

Comment: it is not deleting data from `UAssignment_Rights`

Comment: @ZoyaSheikh then you didn't insert a row on `Users` that had the same `user_id` on `UAssignment_Rights`

Comment: No, both have same user_id. After deleting row, `Message Displayed that Trigger has executed successfully, but it is not deleting rows from UAssignment_Right`

Comment: @ZoyaSheikh Sorry, didn't really understood that you were using a trigger to **delete** rows, since you were using the `Inserted` pseudo table. Updated my answer now

Comment: @ZoyaSheikh There's no `Updated` pseudo table on triggers, just `Inserted` and `Deleted`, so you'll need to use both on the nex trigger depending on what you want to do